# How to update metadata easily Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

When I create a new version for the App Store (because I want to change the keywords and metadata for ASO purposes), most things are gone such as the app icon etc. How do I copy over the missing metadata from the old version?

Also, is there a way to create a new version of the app just to improve ASO, without uploading a new build?

Thanks.

Comment: now a days you can't edit metadata without uploading new build. App Icon in itunesconnect use Icon from new build that you upload.

Comment: You say "most things are gone". Like what (besides the icon which comes from the build)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a complete backup of your app store metadata.

With the following tool you can create an export.
 - You will receive an ZIP file by email with all your metadata
 - Then you can edit the files locally or just import all the data whenever you need it

Scroll down on the following page to find the tool:
https://www.iwantanelephant.com/app-store-export-import/